# PHP form with checkbox and verification does't work

Tags: php, forms, email

i"m new here and i don't understand php at all, but i need to do a contact form with checkbox and verification, this is my code ( is a frankenstein code). 
I need that my form send an email with the information avoiding spam, and missing information, and when mail arrive has all the details in header like a mail to reply, subject and all.

if you can post an correct code will be wonderful.
thanks in advance

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="app.php">
  <label for="name">*Nombre Completo</label>
  <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" size="50">
  <label for="company">*Empresa</label>
  <input  type="text" name="company" maxlength="150" size="50">
  <label for="telephone">Teléfono</label>
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="150" size="50">
  <label for="email">*Email</label>
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="180" size="50">
  <label for="services">*Servicios de Interes</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="apps" />apps<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Marketing Movil" />Marketing Móvil<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="video juegos" />video Juegos<br />

  <label for="comments">*Comentarios</label>

  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
  <div class="hide">Leave this empty:<input name="url" /></div>

  <center><input class="button large" type="submit" value="Submit Form"></center>

</form>





<?php
// if the url field is empty
if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == '')
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "my@mail.com";
    $email_subject = "Contact from web.com";



    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "There were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['full_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['services']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments']))
         {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $full_name = $_POST['full_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // required
    $services = $_POST['services']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required


    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$full_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($full_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Services: ".clean_string($services)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

 //  hacker defense
function clean($var){//request string cleaner
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $var=stripslashes($var); //clean
    $var=mysql_real_escape_string($var); //clean
    return strip_tags($var, '<b><a>');//returning clean var
}

function hackerDefense(){//thanks to Allen Sanford
        // begin hacker defense       
        foreach ($_POST as &$postvalue){    //checking posts
            $postvalue = clean($postvalue);//cleaning the value
        }
} // end hacker defense


?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->
<center>
<img src="images/logo.png" />
  <br>
  <br>
  Thank you for contacting us.  We will be in touch.<br>
<br>
 <a href="index.html">HOME</a></center>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: you don't have a db connection, so mysql_real_escape_string() is going to FAIL every single time and return a boolean false. and for email purposes, SQL escaping is utterly **USELESS**.

Comment: Marc thanks for your comment, what a need to do?

Comment: I find this code, that works fine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548635/php-contact-form-with-checkboxes but when you send it, mail headers are wrong ( mail come with  $email_from = "from@from.com";)  how can fix it

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't an adequate question. What specifically does it do wrong?

Comment: @barmar my code is wrong so mail is not sent

Comment: Enable error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning. Are there any error messages? And get rid of `@` before `mail()`, since that disables error messages.

Comment: @barmar right now when mail came checkboxes information came like this: services, array and not the right values   Form details below.

Full Name: full name
Email: test@test.com
Telephone: 1212121212
Services: Array
Comments: test test test